# Partial String match SQL - Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-like

Trying to do a partial string match here but am getting a problem with the LIKE operator. I'm sure its the syntax but I cannot see it

```
SELECT Name
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Name = b.FullName LIKE '%' + a.Name + '%'
```

I get an error message when I execute this

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.

Comment: what exactly your condition ? you want to check  `b.FullName LIKE '%' + a.Name + '%'`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? show us some sample input and output.

Comment: I have data in Table 1 and Table 2. Table 1 for ex has Peter and Table 2 has Peter Love. Both the tables have over 50 entires. I want to match both and give me a result when it matches. I need to match it partially since if I dont use LIKE operator I get zero results

Comment: you can always split the string and check it with other

Comment: I added answer based on your feedback.

Comment: Fair enough, still struggling with it though. Do you see any problems as to why I am getting the error message in the first place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct Name, FullName
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON (b.FullName LIKE '%' + a.Name + '%' OR a.Name like '%'+b.FullName+'%')
```

Comment: well it didnt give me an error but didnt give me the results either. This time it matched a word and gave me 10 results when there is only 1 match

Comment: worked like a charm, now if I have more than one matches, lets say 3 matches, can I display all of them?

Comment: If i understood your question rightly, above query should do that too

Comment: No it skips out the repeats, I think the distinct keyword does that. It only shows the unique results

Comment: Add fullname also in the select list..try the updated solution.. if you are getting single column, what difference does that make to have repeated values..

Comment: I will be using the code to display more data later on not just the one column, so if there are repeats I would like to see them too. FYI your answer worked! Thank you very much... Well this is just a start, I have to do a lot more coding.. lol

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue with Postgres.
Its a bit messy, but I used textcat to add the wildcard since the above '%'+ didn't play well with my query on Metabase

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct Name, FullName
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON b.FullName LIKE textcat(textcat('%',a.Name),'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT Name
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON b.FullName LIKE '%' + a.Name + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this is what you want

```
DECLARE @Tablle1 TABLE(id int identity(1,1),Name varchar(20))
DECLARE @Tablle2 TABLE(id int identity(1,1),FullName varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @Tablle1
(
    Name
)
VALUES
(
    'Bob'
),
('Sam');

INSERT INTO @Tablle2
(
    FullName
)
VALUES
(
    'Bob M'
),
('Gary');

SELECT b.FullName
    FROM @Tablle1 a
    INNER JOIN @Tablle2 b
    ON b.FullName like '%' + a.Name + '%'
```

and output is

```
FullName
Bob M
```

Comment: I already have the tables and dont need to create them again.
Can you write the code without creating the tables

Comment: These are table variables just to show you example of your data and and output you want from that data

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare FullName with Name using LIKE but already you are matching the columns to check if they are equal.There doesnt seem any logic.

If you just need name that match pattern like a.Name you can opt for following query :

```
SELECT        a.Name, b.FullName
FROM            [1table] AS a INNER JOIN
                         [2table] AS b ON a.Name = b.FullName
WHERE        (b.FullName LIKE N'%a.Name%')
```

Comment: it did not give any results since when you match them you're doing a full match and then showing the results "where statement"
I think thats what the logic is doing if im not wrong thats why its not showing any results